# Unity ignore collisions on the same layer

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to use Physics.IgnoreCollision to avoid bullets hitting themselves.
The bullets are spawned on layer 8. Why is this not working? How can you ignore collisions with everything on the same layer?

```
// bulletscript.cs
gameObject.layer = 8;

// maingamescript.cs
Physics.IgnoreCollision(8,8);
```

There may also be other objects on layer 8 that should also be ignored.
(for example, the player ship).

Comment: You code is correct, that change just take some time to become effective inside unity, check my answer (so actually that's a unity fault, I though they had fixed that issue). If my answer don't work then you have to search the solution in some other script overriding your settings.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why not use the handy dandy Physics Manager. Go to Edit->Project Settings-> Physics and set up the proper layer collisions. 
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Go to [Physics Manager](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PhysicsManager.html) and un-check the layer with itself to avoid collision.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Troubleshot:**

1. Unity bug, try to update to latest Unity 5.3.x (5.4 currently has nasty bugs)
2. Make sure the bullets and players are effectively in the wanted layer
3. The change in layer takes some time to take effect (few frames), since bullet are fast, you are probably encurring in that lag (so in the time the change take effect the bullet already hitted the target)
4. The best way is to have a Bullet Prefab that is spawned already in the correct layer, you can later customize that by changin graphics at runtime if you like, but to avoid the lag it should be instantiated already in the correct layer.

There is no need to go to physics manager, the OP already do the correct code equivalent to the physics manager. The real problem is that the GameObject should be already instantiated with the correct layer, because layer update may take some time to get effective.

Another workaround is to disable/reenable the collider.

Comment: Please delete this. There are already answers that actually answered this question. This does not. **"try to update to latest Unity 3.3.x (3.4 currently has nasty bugs)"** Really? Update to Unity 3.3.x that was made more than 5 years ago? How does this solve the problem? OP should as well downgrade to Windows 95.

Comment: Sorry was meaning unity 5.3.x :) Anyway, those answers are useless because they are just the Editor way to achieve what the OP is trying already to achieve programmatically, so those do not solve the problem because have the same effect of the OP code, the problem is infact elsewhere (infact my answer is different from the other as well). The problem is the change propagation time, not the usage of the editor. Those may force to indirectly use a predefined layer, but that is just a side effect and of no use for future readers since that's deeply documented inside Unity

Comment: Oh ok. The 3.3.x scared me. I am glad to know you meant 5.4. For the other answers, I really don't think they are useless. The only time it would be useless is if the OP wants to disable the collision then enable it late on. In this case, OP only wants to disable the collision. Doing this from the Editor is totally fine. #3 in your answer sounds like the actual problem.

Comment: I actually mean change it from the Editor and forget doing with with code.  Of-course, change the layer from the Editor too. OP should use code for this only if he wants to disable the collision then enable it at some point. If he only wants to disable it just like he mentioned in the question then there is no need to do that from code. It's a waste code. +1 for your #3 and #4.

Comment: I think it may have been the case that the bullet already hit the target before the code was working. When I use the collision physics manager it works, so that may have been the problem. Not sure which answer to mark as correct... In my case the problem was solved by using the physics manager.

Comment: Mark wich one you prefer, the physics manager fix the problem but indirectly, in the end only the OP know wich answer is more usefull to him. (the problem is the lag, you fix it by physix manageR)